# How to change value of data-top and data-range in DIV using jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

Hi there guys is anyone knows how to change the attribute value of data-top and data-range in jQuery using the select option

what I want to happen is when I select on one of the option i.e. `cap`, `vol`, and `cat` the value of `data-order="cap"` in div will be changed using jQuery

here is the code of div

```
<div id="heatmap" class="cr-heatmap-widget" data-top="10" data-range="24H" data-order="cat" style="width: 370px; height: 250px;">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://cryptorank.io/heatmaps">
        Market State by Cryptorank
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://cryptorank.io/widget/market-state.js"></script>
```

Here is the code for select-box

```
<div class="select-dropdown">
    <select id="showby">
        <option value="cap">Market Cap</option>
        <option value="vol">Volume</option>
        <option value="cat">Category</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#showby").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = jQuery(this).children("option:selected").val();
        jQuery('#heatmap').attr('data-order',selectedCountry)
    });
});
```

Here's the image for reference the select box has 3 option `cat`,`vol` so when I select any of the three the coins below will be change
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LVkp.png)

Comment: I already edited the post

Comment: nothing changes whatever I select on the selectbox here's my site https://www.protrada.com/heatmap/

Comment: right now the default value of data-order is market cap so if ever I choose the volume or category the coins below will change however it's not changing

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding to clarify there are 3 attributes I want to know how to change when selecting a selectbox data-top, data-range, and data-order. I just give an example of data-order instead of data-top and data-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Give other 2 select-boxes some `id` (lets say `topby` and `periodby`),

b) After that add code like below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#showby").change(function(){
       var selectedCountry = jQuery(this).val();
       jQuery('#heatmap').attr('data-order',selectedCountry);
   });
   jQuery("#topby").change(function(){
        var topBy = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#heatmap').attr('data-top',topBy);
    });
    
    jQuery("#periodby").change(function(){
        var periodBy = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#heatmap').attr('data-range',periodBy);
    });
});
```

Comment: how about the data-order

Comment: Yes thanks it's working now. My problem now is the script is not reloading so the coins will refresh also